# How to transpose date column into rows?

Tags: sql-server

I have a row in database which is saving the number of leaves any employee avails. The data is something like this.

```
ID   EmpCode   DateFrom    DateTo
1    101       2020-01-07  2020-01-10
2    194       2020-02-02  2020-02-03
```

I want to convert the data into rows something like this

```
EmpCode   LeaveDate
101       2020-01-07
101       2020-01-08
101       2020-01-09
101       2020-01-10
194       2020-02-02
194       2020-02-03
```

Is this something possible ?

Comment: I suggest investing in a calendar table/

Answer (score 1):

As I mention, a [calender table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/bones-of-sql-the-calendar-table) would be the easiest method, then you can simply do something like this:

```
SELECT YT.EmpCode,
       C.CalendarDate AS LeaveDate
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN dbo.CalendarTable C ON C.CalendarDate BETWEEN YT.DateFrom AND YT.DateTo;
```

Without a Calendar Table, you can use a Tally Table or inline Tally to create the rows:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int,
                            EmpCode int,
                            DateFrom date,
                            DateTo date);

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ID,
                           EmpCode,
                           DateFrom,
                           DateTo)
VALUES (1,101,'2020-01-07','2020-01-10'),
       (2,194,'2020-02-02','2020-02-03');

GO


WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT --TOP(SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY, DateFrom, DateTo))+1 FROM dbo.YourTable) --TOP probably isn't needed here. Depends on the size of your table, and how many rows you're  going to need. 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --1,000 days
SELECT YT.EmpCode,
       DATEADD(DAY, T.I, YT.DateFrom) AS LeaveDate
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN Tally T ON T.I <= DATEDIFF(DAY, YT.DateFrom, YT.DateTo)
ORDER BY YT.EmpCode,
         LeaveDate;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
GO
```